# How to change DBgrid row value?

Tags: delphi

I would like to change DBgrid row value with outside data, how to achieve that?

For example i would like to add Tedit value into dbgrid selected row column(for example 5) via button click.

Also, i would like to add value from 1 dbgrid to another dbgrid.(Add to an existing number, not replace).

Comment: Forget trying to modify the values in the dbgrid directly - it will fight you every inch of the waThe correct way to do this is to modify the value of the field of the dataset supplying the dby,  grid's data for the column of interest.

Comment: @MartynA Yeah, i have heard about it before. Do you have any stored example of such a process? Those are my first days with dbgrids, dont know how to update any values yet, and worse is that I dont know where should I look for any tips. I know I can do it directly from a dgbrid but that's not the point.

Comment: Sounds like you need a tutorial on working with Delphi datasets and db-aware controls.  In Delphi, db-aware controls like TDBEdit and TDBGrid are controls which automatically update themselves when the data in the dataset supplying them (via a TDataSource) changes.

Comment: http://etutorials.org/Programming/mastering+delphi+7/Part+III+Delphi+Database-Oriented+Architectures/

Comment: You don't' edit or change the data in a TDBGrid. You change the data in the dataset that it is connected to instead. The TDBGrid merely displays the data from that dataset; it doesn't hold the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a dataset connected to db-aware controls like TDBEdit and TDBGrid via a TDataSource.  Delphi's db-aware controls are basically the default ones which come with Delphi and are displayed on the `Data controls` tab of its Component Palette plus any 3rd-party ones that you install.  The reason they are called db-aware is because they are written so that the values they display are automatically derived from the related fields of the dataset.

Also suppose that the dataset is called Table1 and has a CustomerName field that you want to change.  The *simplest* code which will achieve that is something like:

```
Table1.Edit;  // put table one into dsEdit state so that field values can be changes
Table1.FieldByName('CustomerName').AsString := 'Jones';
Table1.Post;  // save the change(s) to Table1
```

More optimal code might be

```
Table1.Edit;
try
  Table1.DisableControls;  //  this prevents the db-aware controls updating on-screen while the changes are made
  Table1.FieldByName('CustomerName').AsString := 'Jones';
  Table1.FieldByName('CustomeCountry').AsString := 'DE@;
finally
  Table1.Post;
  Table1.EnableControls; //  Eable screen updating od the db-aware controls again
end;
```

That would update the values displayed in DBEdit controls linked to the CustomerName and CustomerCountry fields **and** in the CustomerName and CustomerCountry cells of the current (i.e. highlighted) row in the DBGrid, because the current row in the DBGrid always tracks the current row in the connected dataset.

If you really do want to update a given column from a TEdit's text you could do that like this:

```
Table1.Edit;
DBGrid1.Columns[5].Field.AsString := Edit1.Text; 
Table1.Post;
```